# Controling language on iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

We have an Xcode project that we are using for 7 different apps that are all published to app store. In the project there are 5 languages defined, but depending on the app only a subset of the languages are used. In the app store we only want to display max three languages per app. We might be able to control number of languageswith code in the project, or (probably better) with frameworks and different projects, but it would off course be much easirer for us if it is possible to controll with settings on the individual apps in Xcode. So is there a setting in Xcode or some other smart way of achiving this control of languages?

Comment: are you doing  this with  Localization?

Answer (score 0):

Select your localize .string file and mark it as available or unavailable for any Target Membership.

[image]